# Python - writing lines from file into IRC buffer

Tags: python, scripting, text, irc, glob

Ok, so I am trying to write a Python script for XCHAT that will allow me to type "/hookcommand filename" and then will print that file line by line into my irc buffer.

EDIT:  Here is what I have now

```
__module_name__ = "scroll.py"
__module_version__ = "1.0"
__module_description__ = "script to scroll contents of txt file on irc"

import xchat, random, os, glob, string

def gg(ascii):
    ascii = glob.glob("F:\irc\as\*.txt")
        for textfile in ascii:
            f = open(textfile, 'r')

def gg_cb(word, word_eol, userdata):
    ascii = gg(word[0])
    xchat.command("msg %s %s"%(xchat.get_info('channel'), ascii))
    return xchat.EAT_ALL


xchat.hook_command("gg", gg_cb, help="/gg filename to use")
```

Comment: What is the utility of textfile and f in gg() ?

Comment: I thought I had to do a for loop to read the lines from the file, is it not needed?

Comment: It is needed. You currently have a loop to open the files that glob returns. Then you need a loop to get the lines in each file. Then (and this is important), you need to actually get those lines to xchat. At the moment, you open each file (`f = open(...`), then you ignore it.

Comment: So should I add something along the lines of `for line in f: print line,` ?  If so, where do I place it because when I tried that, I received `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: Yes, that's a good start. It goes after the `f = ...` line, because you have to set `f` before you can use it. Of course, then you'll need to send each line to xchat, but getting them to print out is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first problem is that you're referring to a variable ascii before you define it:

```
ascii = gg(ascii)
```

Try making that:

```
ascii = gg(word[0])
```

Next, you're opening each file returned by glob... only to do absolutely nothing with them. I'm not going to give you the code for this: please try to work out what it's doing or not doing for yourself. One tip: the xchat interface is an extra complication. Try to get it working in plain Python first, then connect it to xchat.

There may well be other problems - I don't know the xchat api.

When you say "not working", try to specify exactly how it's not working. Is there an error message? Does it do the wrong thing? What have you tried?

Comment: There are other problems: see where `f` is used in `gg`.

Comment: I added the revised bit to my original post.  Whenever I type "/gg nameoftextfile" my nick prints "None" to my IRC channel and nothing else.

Comment: @nmichaels: True. I've added some details to the answer.